# How can I open the Jaeger UI(run in Istio) in a remote browser, not the localhost machine

Tags: kubernetes, istio, jaeger

The **Istio (version 1.0.6)** official document says:

We can access the Jaeger UI by the following action:

> Kubectl port-forward -n istio-system $(kubectl get pod -n istio-system -l app=jaeger -o jsonpath=’{.items[0].metadata.name}’) 16686:16686 &

Then we can use `http://localhost:16686`.
But the localhost is a Linux machine, it doesn't have a browser.
I must open the browser on a remote machine.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I understood wrong the scenario. In istio-system namespace you have the tracing pod. Have you tried to expose that service? It should give you a route to it. And if you have external access to your cluster, then you should be able to access to the jaeger UI.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of doing this. The `port-forward` works fine on Google Cloud Shell. If you are using GKE, then I strongly recommend using Cloud Shell, and `port-forward` as it is the easiest way. On other clouds, I don't know.

What is suggesting Stefan would work. You can edit the jaeger service with `kubectl edit svc jaeger-query`, then change the type of the service from `ClusterIP` to `NodePort`. Finally, you can access the service with `NODE_IP:PORT` (any node). If you do `kubectl get svc`, you will see the new port assigned to the service.
Note: You might need to open a firewall rule for that port.

You can also make the service type `LoadBalancer`, if you have a control plane to set up an external IP address. This would be a more expensive solution, but you would have a dedicated external IP address for your service.

There are more ways, but I would say these are the appropriate ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) service using the `app: jaeger` selector to expose the UI outside the cluster.

Comment: could you elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl port-forward` command default is expose to `localhost` network only, try to add `--address 0.0.0.0`

```
$ kubectl port-forward -n istio-system \
 $(kubectl get pod -n istio-system -l app=jaeger -o jsonpath=’{.items[0].metadata.name}’) \
  --address 0.0.0.0 16686:16686 &
```

see [kubectl command reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a LB that opens jaeger-ui.

kubectl apply -f jaeger-nlb.yaml

*jaeger-nlb.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jaeger-ui-nlb
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    app: jaeger
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-timeout: "60"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: "http"
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: tcp
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 16686   
  selector:
    app: jaeger
  type: LoadBalancer
```